# regex match subdomain

Tags: regex, go

I need a regex that matches all the subdomains of a specific domain. The content media type is unknown (i.g. may be urlencoded, json etc)
So far I've got this simple regex 
`` re, err := regexp.Compile(`([-a-z0-9])+[.](.*)domain.com`) ``

The issue is that for a string such this below the whole string is [Found](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAll) instead to get the specific sudomains extracted such `prefix1-prefix2.domain.com` so the question is what regexp do I need to get only the subdomains without the extra string (i.e `%2Fdocument...`)

`prefix1-prefix2.domain.com%2Fdocument%2F%3Fusp%3Dmkt_docs%26lng%3Den&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fprefix1-prefix2.domain.com%2Fdocument%2F%3Fusp%3Dmkt_docs%26lng%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greedy `(.*)` in your regex is matching all the stuff that you don't want, you can remove that. Also, I escaped your `.` characters and moved your `+` to be inside the capture group.

Change your regex to: `([-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com` or in the context of your code:

```
regexp.Compile(`([-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com`)
```

Here's a [regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/VSOi0w/1) you can test it with.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use [url](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package that can parse URL for  you and then check domain.  Otherwise you can get some pitfalls like symbols escaping etc.

https://play.golang.org/p/6so9FTfOSo

Upd: updated the recipe, also there’s an error in source URL - last `%` is not followed by hex code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

var s = "prefix1-prefix2.domain.com%2Fdocument%2F%3Fusp%3Dmkt_docs%26lng%3Den&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fprefix1-prefix2.domain.com%2Fdocument%2F%3Fusp%3Dmkt_docs%26lng"

func main() {
    s2, err := url.QueryUnescape(s)
    u, err := url.Parse(s2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    if u.Scheme == "" {
        s2 = "https://" + s2
    }
    fmt.Println(s2, err)
    u, err = url.Parse(s2)

    fmt.Printf("%#v %v", u, err)

    fmt.Println(u.Host)
    if strings.HasSuffix(u.Host, ".domain.com") {
        fmt.Println("subdomain!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better option, parsing URLs can quickly become complex and a URL library will be better able to pull out the relevant URL parts.

Comment: Quite agree - that’s the way I recommend ;) it has one more advantage url lib checks url for errors and invalid sequences. I’ve put a recipe above.

Comment: I've used it to extract URLs from JavaScript(source code) and I ended up with a lot of garbage. I wouldn't recommend it for data "extraction" or validation. It's like that because of legacy reasons and the Go team doesn't want to make it a data extraction/validation tool anyway.

Comment: @Books with url?  how did you get that garbage with `url`? It produces much few variants then regexp parsing. Variants can be easily checked as I showed above with `u.Schema`. When you parse with regexp you have to handle many variants with different symbols.